# MVC 4 - custom memebership provider with Oracle database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to build website with MVC 4 on top of Oracle database. Also I don't want these webpages_Membership or webpages_OAuthMembership tables. Is it necessary to write my own membership provider and role provider? I found [this](http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/11/10/simplemembershipprovider-in-mvc4-for-mysql-oracle-and-more-with-llblgen/) - it might be good solution, but maybe there is a simplier way?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the tables created by Simple Membership Provider, from solution explorer go to Filters, `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` and make sure `autoCreateTables` is set to `false`:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContext", "TableToPointTo", 
"UserIdColumn", "UserNameColumn", autoCreateTables: false);
```

Simple Membership Provider inherits from Extended Membership Provider so if you wanted to create your own custom provider you would do something like this:

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : ExtendedMembershipProvider
{
    // inherited methods
}
```

If you want to look at the logic in the SimpleMembershipProvider class, you can see the source code [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/bf897646cb14#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs).

Comment: I've struggled with this. For some reason, simple membership does not seem to work with Oracle. have you succeeded in getting this to work?